# Program Running in Windows\SysWOW64 on user logon instead of Program Files

Tags: c#, windows, wix, resources, startup

I wrote a bootstrapper in C# that launches on user logon and requires access to resources in its install location (Program Files). It cannot locate its resources when launched on user logon. The program launches on user logon because I have used WIX toolkit to create an installer which adds a registry entry to HKMU under 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'. Here is the WIX wxs part that creates the registry entry:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <!-- Add to system start-up -->
  <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="MYGUIDISHERE">
    <RegistryValue Id="BHWM.rst"
                   Root="HKMU"
                   Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
                   Action="write"
                   Type="string"
                   Name="My Program Name"
                   Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]Bootstrapper.exe"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

And INSTALLFOLDER is defined as:

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyCompanyName"\>
```

The file paths are not absolute, and I wanted to keep them this way. I added a printout to my bootstrapper that prints the absolute path of one of the resources:

```
Path.GetFullPath("jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll")
```

Which revealed it was looking for the resource under 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll' instead of the desired 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompanyName\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll' (the INSTALLFOLDER), but strangely when printing the location of the application base directory from the bootstrapper using:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

The output is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompanyName'. I could use this to create an absolute path to my resources but as it is a bootstrapper, it also effects how the program that is being launched by the bootstrapper accesses the same resources. I could pass the application base directory to the program being launched as a parameter but I wanted to avoid this. Is there a way I can run the bootstrapper on user logon to refer to these resources using a reference path? (so not in 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64')

*Note: Bootstrapper runs fine when running start menu/desktop shortcuts on running EXE from Program Files directory*

Comment: Why are you putting a 64 bit dll in the Program Files (x86) folder?

Comment: @jdweng I have another issue with configuring WIX to use x64 platform configuration

Comment: Do you know how dll got installed in the Windows folder?  I think method 1 was used instead of method 2.  See : http://www.dlldownloader.com/jvm-dll/

Comment: @jdweng It's one of a few resources I need the bootstrapper to access. The JVM DLL is part of a custom Java Runtime Environment from JLink. The bootstrapper uses the stripped down custom runtime environment to launch a Java program with a set of libraries - this Java program also references the resource inside my program installation directory (Program Files x86). The DLL is not installed in the Windows folder and I don't want it to be - the path to it should be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompanyName\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll'

Comment: Is there any environmental variables being used?  Try from cmd.exe >Set.  Did you try to uninstall the dll (go to Control Panel Software and uninstall) and then use method 2 to reinstall? Trying to figure out why it is looking in wrong location.

Comment: @jdweng No environment variables. The DLL is moved to the install directory. The WIX installer is configured to copy the JRE that's generated by JLink to 'Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\jre' so that when the bootstrapper launches it can refer to the DLL

Comment: The link I provided say if method 2 fails try method 3.